# Converting coefficients from a linear model into percentages

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, logarithm, percentage

I've got two different sets of regression models, one set is linear and the other log-log. The two models have the same independent variables but different dependent variables. I'm looking for a way to make meaningful comparisons about the effects of the independent variables on the different dependents.

At the moment my interpretation of the log-log model is in percentage change, which doesn't allow for easy comparison to the coefficients from the linear model.

I've been advised to convert the coefficients from the linear model into percentages, but I can't find out how this should be done. Can anyone help? I'm in the final stages of my project and I certainly don't want to go back and run all the linear models as log-log.

The linear models have a boxcox transformed dependent variables (lambada 0.14) and I've centered these variables.

Thanks in advance!